# How to IMPORT this blocked attachments from gmail to another gmail?

Tags: gmail, incoming-mail

By enabling **POP** feature, I successfully imported almost all gmail inbox into new gmail inbox except **391** mails with

```
((has:attachment OR has:drive) .dll)
```

Due to gmail blocked this `.dll` attachments, how to import leftover ".dll" files also to my new gmail inbox?

I learned that enabling **IMAP** will help me. But I am new to **IMAP** thing in gmail.